# Excel: Comma after every word in column

Tags: excel

I am looking to add a comma after every word in a particular column (there are 5 others) and on all its rows. I've seen a number of questions similar such as after first word only etc, but not on all words as I require.

I presume it would be a =CONCATENATE formula.

The outcome to be as follows:

```
COLUMN 1
test test test test

COLUMN 1
test, test, test, test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split the column into words then concatenate back with the commas, but why not just do a find and replace on spaces, replacing them with a comma and space?

Comment: Stupidly simply ha, can't believe I missed the most obvious way. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, everyone has those days. ;)